# PHP Websocket possibly not going through Cloudflare at all?

Tags: php, websocket

I'm currently using Ratchet PHP Websockets example code (http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world) and when I try to run the Websocket it doesn't output anything but does show that it's "live".

On my website I'm using the very same JS code as the example except using `wss://` as my website is going through Cloudflare's SSL. Now my question is, when I try to connect to the websocket, in my Chrome developer tools it just continuously shows pending and will terminate if I turn the websocket off.

I cannot find a way to debug what is going on with it, I'm using the ports that Cloudflare allows me to use (which is :8443) and I am on a plan where Websockets are supported by Cloudflare. But I cannot seem to find any answers about using Websockets through cloudflare and when I turn on `error_reporting` it doesn't seem to output anything either.

Is it something with Cloudflare? When I type `php runwebsocket.php` is it supposed to output something besides nothing?

When I used this script for the Websockets (https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets) it would output if a client has connected to the socket but would still give me the same issue where it's not actually fully connecting to it.

**EDIT:** When I go to the Websocket Echo testing site when I try to connect to my socket it just doesn't output anything either.

**EDIT #2:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require('vendor/autoload.php'); // composer require cboden/ratchet

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use AppSocket\Notifications;

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Notifications()
        )
    ),
    8443
);
$server->run();
```

Code for `AppSocket\Notifications`

```
<?php
namespace AppSocket;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Notifications implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }
    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {

                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
        echo "Yay";
    }
    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

        $this->clients->detach($conn);
        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```